# Сигн для etxt api на Python

Tags: python

Не могу сделать сигн для etxt api на Python
Etxt API [ссылка](https://www.etxt.ru/api/)
Там написано:

Подпись запроса
Чтобы удостовериться, что запрос отправлен действительно вами, а не злоумышленниками от лица вашего приложения, все запросы к API должны быть подписаны. Результат расчета подписи вы должны передать в параметре sign. Биржа проверит подпись и выполнит запрос только если подпись правильная.
Алгоритм использует отдельный ключ, api_pass, который мы настоятельно рекомендуем вам хранить только на ваших серверах и использовать только при запросах с них к серверу Биржи. Данный ключ задается в разделе "Личная информация/Настройки интерфейса".

```
sign = md5(params.md5(api_pass.'api-pass'))
```

Значение params — это конкатенация пар «имя=значение» отсортированных в алфавитом порядке по «имя», где «имя» — это название параметра, передаваемого в функцию API, «значение» — значение параметра. Разделитель в конкатенации не используется. Параметр sign при расчете подписи не учитывается, все остальные параметры запроса должны учитываться при расчете.
Безопасность схемы основывается на том, что api_pass знаете только вы и Биржа. Поэтому никогда не раскрывайте его третьим лицам. Если у вас возникли сомнения в безопасности api_pass, измените его в настройках профиля.

Пытался написать такой код, но API возвращает "Подпись не верна"

```
import requests
import hashlib
def md5(string):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(string.encode('utf-8'))
    return m.hexdigest()
token='здесь был мой токен'
method='users.getUser'
login=input('Введите логин пользователя : ')
a='login='+login+'method='+method+'token='+token
params=md5(a)
key=md5('здесь был мой ключ api')
sign=md5(params+key)
print(a)
r=requests.get('https://www.etxt.ru/api/json/',params={'login':login,'method':method,'sign':sign,'token':token})
print(r.text)
```

Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sign = md5(params + md5(api_pass + 'api-pass'));
```

[Оператор конкатенации `.`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php) в PHP равен оператору `+` в Python.